# Death in Christmas Special not a fixed point in time?

Tags: doctor-who

In [The Doctor, the Widow and the Wardrobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor,_the_Widow_and_the_Wardrobe) she saves her husband, but with that she modifies a fixed point in time, how is this possible? Is it a slight/tolerable nuance of a Christmas Special?

Comment: Presumably this Death was not written down. Since he (and his crew) vanished over the Channel it is concievable they were just *lost*, basically MIA not KIA. Therefore his death was not a fixed point in time. Basically the same as in *The Waters of Mars*, where **Time** didn't care the two young people survived as long as Adelaide bit the dust.

Comment: What made that a fixed point?

Comment: Well his "death" was very significant - if it didn't happen she would probably never save the trees. But I like how @BMWurm pointed out it could be viewed as MIA rather than KIA and thus it wouldn't be even considerable for a fixed point...

Comment: @Michal: does the Doctor say her husband’s death is a fixed point in time? If not, there’s no reason to assume it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you misinterpreted the ending of the episode: she did save her husband, but she didn't change anything.

She *had always* saved her husband.

When her husband dies in the opening part of the show, we see him flying his plane back from a mission when he runs into a bright light and disappears. She gets a message from the RAF that her husband's plane went down and he has died, but *they never found him*. They didn't recover his body or his plane, he's merely missing and presumed dead.

What had actually happened is that the "widow", while piloting the tree-people's ship, had also pulled her husband into the future with her. The reason his plane "disappeared" was because he had time traveled forward (it's not really clear how far) and ended up at home on Christmas.

Comment: I like this interpretation. Simple and makes absolutely sense. I guess I got fooled by wibbly wobbly. Thanks!